# Test execution gets stopped after an assertion error in pytest With Fixtures

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, data-driven-tests

I am new to Python ,

For the data driven testing, if there is 10tests , and the assertion fails   [  AssertionError.  ] for 4th  test ,  then the rest of the 6 data sets are not considered for execution and the program gets stopped at that point completely. I want test to continue even if one dataset fails ? How can we achieve with fixtures ? Or is there any other way ?

We set up a fixture for Data Driven Testing  using Fixtures.

========== TEST DATA ============

```
Test data is defined in Json  File [ array of JSON Objects ]
```

==============. Fixture Code =========

```
from _pytest.fixtures import fixture

users_json_files_path=. “//Pathto_Input_Json_File”.   

@fixture(params=load_jsondata(users_json_files_path))
def users_testdata(request):

    user_test_data=request.param
    return user_test_data
```

=========== Passing Fixture to Test Method . ==============

```
def test_one(users_testdata):    
      assert len(users_not_present == 0 ,"Following Users not present :: " + str(users_not_present)
```

Thanks,
Deepti

Comment: I'm curious why you're importing from `_pytest` rather than from `pytest`?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asserting. You can use this for your case:
https://pypi.org/project/pytest_check/